# How to avoid casts with generalized type constraint?

Tags: scala, types

I'm designing the following trait and method:

```
trait Reader[T]{
  def read(): T
}

def rd[T, A](r: Reader[T])(implicit ev: T =:= Option[A]): Either[String, A] = r.read() match {
  case Some(a) => Right(a) // <---- compile error here
  case None => Left("End reached")
}
```

The thing is I got compile error in the code above:

```
Error:(17, 27) type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: A
    case Some(a) => Right(a)
```

But when I add the type explicitly it compiles with a warning:

```
trait Reader[T]{
  def read(): T
}

def rd[T, A](r: Reader[T])(implicit ev: T =:= Option[A]): Either[String, A] = r.read() match {
  case Some(a: A) => Right(a) // <--- Warning here
  case None => Left("End reached")
}
```

The warning:

```
Warning:(17, 18) abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    case Some(a: A) => Right(a)
```

Is it possible to eliminate this cast?

Comment: The definition of `read()` is troublesome to me. Perhaps redefinition is in order? `trait Reader[T] { def read(): Option[T] }`

Comment: @BobDalgleish Is it necessary to constaint `Reader` to emit `Option` only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=:=` class actually has an `apply` method that safely converts from its first type parameter to its second. So this works:

```
def rd[T, A](r: Reader[T])(implicit ev: T =:= Option[A]): Either[String, A] = ev(r.read()) match {
  case Some(a) => Right(a)
  case None => Left("End reached")
}
```